# typeScript transpiling and creating cross-browser friendly code

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer

Does TypeScript remove the concern whether you should use code like this (when you know some browsers like IE might not be supporting the `indexOf`?)

```
arrValues.indexOf('Sam') > -1
```

Does the TypeScript transpiling process produce the proper JavaScript code that is guaranteed to run across all browsers? (Assuming TypeScript config is set to ES5).

Comment: Typescript compiler does not create browser specific code , it is still the developers responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does perform a number of down-level compilations, but `indexOf` is not one of them. If you are targeting ECMAScript 5, `indexOf` would be included anyway, because it was in the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14) - but even if you were to target ECMAScript 3 it wouldn't be fixed for you.

In all cases, down-level compilation is between versions of the standard, not to smooth browser compatibility.

Two examples of down-level compilations are below. In each case, the output depends on the version your are targeting with `target: "ES5"` flags.

## let / const

TypeScript. Allows block-scoped variables to be used.

```
const x = 'loaded';

{
    const x = 'new value';
}

// loaded
console.log(x);
```

JavaScript. The inner variable `x` is renamed to `x_1` to prevent a naming collision.

```
var x = 'loaded';
{
    var x_1 = 'new value';
}
// loaded
console.log(x);
```

## Iteration

TypeScript. Allows the `for-of` loop to be used.

```
const x = "loaded";

for (const char of x) {
    console.log(char);
}
```

JavaScript. Loop converted into a far less graceful, but moderately more compatible for loop.

```
var x = "loaded";
for (var _i = 0, x_1 = x; _i < x_1.length; _i++) {
    var char = x_1[_i];
    console.log(char);
}
```